# Can we configure the folders to be deployed in respective places in webapp directory in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, ant

I have a web project where the structural architecture is not standard like following

```
- src
  - main
  - test
- Web-INF
etc.
```

The folders are pretty random and we were using `ant` to manually copy class files and jars from respective locations to webapp folder inside Tomcat and pasting in respective places.

Is there a way in tomcat itself which lets us configure what and where to pick the files for respective folders inside webapps?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such an option, and would be severely confused if I came new into an organization that did this. The layout of a web application is pretty much standardized, and there's not much benefit from reinventing the wheel. I feel that personal effort is better spent elsewhere than configuring runtime environments in a way that new people on the team need an intense onboarding and unlearn whatever they've learned about the technology.

You're not stating a reason for your code to be in that organization - but the use of Ant makes me expect that it's been this way for a pretty long time. Is the build process a pain? What problem would you expect to solve with a nonstandard layout on tomcat?

If I can prescribe something: Don't go this route, stick with the standard. If the difference between your source tree and the final WAR file bothers you: Change the source tree organization. But really, it doesn't matter: The source should be organized in a way that makes sense for the source, the build process is there so that you don't need to think twice about the deployment format. It's a non-issue.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, but it's just something we have to follow.

Comment: I hope you only have to follow the current source code layout, not the plans to customize Tomcat's (or the servlet spec's) layout of a webapp. The first is acceptable, the second not.